# Recursive conditions - missing base case

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've wrapped my head around recursion, and am now trying to put it into into practical application without a stack overflow (or doing the Fibonacci sequence (again)! Pun intended.

In my example I've looping over an array of similar items until by ransom chance the element is unique. Job done. 
Do you always need a base case AND  recursive case AND termination conditions for any recursive function?? I can't think of a base case for this example.

```
var myArray = ["bananas", "bananas", "bananas", "bananas", "Gwen Stefani!"];

var tries = 0;
alert(getIt(myArray, tries));

function getIt(arr, num)
{
  r = Math.floor(Math.random()* arr.length);

  // Base case
  // something here??
  // but only if we don't need to call
  // the recursive function

  // termination case
  if (arr[r] != "bananas") 
    {
            alert("Found on attempt " + num);
        return arr[r];
    }

  // Recursive case
  return getIt(arr, num+1);
}
```

Comment: Isn't the termination case the base case?

Comment: Well, I can't see what could be missing here, your snippet should work as you described...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what terms you're using, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursive_functions_and_algorithms (for example) has the base and terminating cases meaning the same thing. In your code, the termination case is the base case as it is what produces the result.

As a side note, you could do this:

```
alert(getIt(myArray, 0));
```

instead of this:

```
var tries = 0;
alert(getIt(myArray, tries));
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Not trying to split hairs. but should you always initiated recursion with a zero count (instead of a variable which happens to be zero?

Comment: It depends on what is it you're trying to achieve. In the case you show I think it'd always be zero, but you may want to count the first call as attempt 1 in which case you'd pass in a one.